# Could you help me with the word "ahead" in this context?

Tags: word-meaning

They met ahead of the conference.

Does it mean before or after? Dictionary says it is about before the conference, but I think it happened after the conference

Comment: Its before the conference. What made you think of it to be happening after the conference?

Comment: http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/ahead, sense 3a. "ahead of".

Answer (score 1):

> They met ahead of the conference.

This means they met *before* the conference. I think you are confused as *[ahead (#2)](http://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=ahead)* also means toward the future, at a later time. But to understand this sentence, think this way...

> You are two feet **ahead** of your friend. So, you are *before* your friend and he's *after* you in a queue.

This is just an example to make you understand that *ahead* is *before*. Kindly do not consider this as a concrete evidence!